# How to get PHP object value to validate by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, object

I know how to use a simple php variable in javascript to validate. But i do not know how to get an object value.

This is my php code:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if ($results) {     
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        $xy = $obj->available_qty;
        echo '<div class="product">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php" name="single_block" onsubmit="validateForm();">';
        echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="product-content"><h3 style="display:inline;">'.$obj->product_name.'</h3><h3 style="float:right;color:green;">Price '.$currency.$obj->price.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        echo '<select name="cutting">
                            <option value="Normal cut">Cutting type</option>
                          <option value="Star cut">Star cut</option>
                          <option value="Rips">Rips</option>
                          <option value="Lolly-pop">Lolly-pop</option>
                          <option value="Rolling cut">Rolling cut</option>
                        </select>';
        echo 'Qty 
        <select name="product_qty">

                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>Kg';
                        echo ' 
        <select name="product_qty_g">
                          <option value="0">  0</option>
                          <option value="050"> 50</option>
                          <option value="100">100</option>
                          <option value="150">150</option>
                          <option value="200">200</option>
                          <option value="250">250</option>
                          <option value="300">300</option>
                          <option value="350">350</option>
                          <option value="400">400</option>
                          <option value="450">450</option>
                          <option value="500">500</option>
                        </select>g';
        echo ' <select name="marination">
                          <option value="0">Marination type</option>
                          <option value="20">Pepper 20/kg</option>
                          <option value="25">Chilly 25/kg</option>
                          <option value="30">Ginger 30/kg</option>
                          <option value="40">Garlic 40/kg</option>
                          <option value="50">Rambo 50/kg</option>
                        </select>';
        echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["single_block"]["product_qty"].value;
        var MyJSStringVar = "<?php Print $xy; ?>";
        if (x > MyJSStringVar) {        
            alert(MyJSStringVar);        
        }
    }   
</script>
```

For the first product it shows the correct quantity from the database, but if I click "Next product", it does not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly thanks  to Barmar for his fast and clear reply, His correction works well. But this simple change we have to do, to get actual validation.

This is final working code:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php" name="single_block" onsubmit="return validateForm(this, '.$xy.');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$xy` changes each time through the loop, but `validateForm()` isn't inside the loop, so it doesn't get the values. You should pass it as an argument. Also, since you have multiple forms with the same name, you need to pass the current form as an argument as well. Finally, a validation function should return `false` if the validation fails, and the `onsubmit` needs to return that, so that the submission will be cancelled.

```
echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php" name="single_block" onsubmit="return validateForm(this, \'$xy\');">';
```

and change the JS to:

```
function validateForm(form, MyJSStringVar) {
    var x = form.product_qty.value;
    if (x > MyJSStringVar) {
        alert(MyJSStringVar);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks   now all the product alerts. But it shows only $xy . I don't think it does validation. Please tell me how to get quantity value of each product from object value.

Comment: Hey mate, I got the answer. I just forgot to remove the single-quote. Your explanation was simple to understand and amazing. Thank you so much